# Invalid policy document. Please check the policy syntax and ensure that Principals are valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

Attempting to create a Resource Policy document for an API Gateway.

I have the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:<acct id>:g2wpcs1pk8/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:<acct_id>:g2wpcs1pk8/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "192.0.2.0/24",
                        "198.51.100.0/24"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I am getting the title error:

`Invalid policy document. Please check the policy syntax and ensure that Principals are valid.`

In the API gateway UI.

I have tried including `ForAnyValue:IpAddress` in the Condition.

Comment: I just copy-pasted your policy in my API and I was able to set it using my account ID and API ID. Did you copy paste the policy from AWS docs? Make sure the policy is json escaped and has no funky space characters.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the issue is that you are specifying the Trust Relationship together with your permissions. So if you remove the Principals, the policy is in fact valid.

Are these permissions for a role? If so, you should remove the Principals and select your trust relationship when creating the role. Similarly, you could attach the policy to a user.

Comment: These permissions are for an API Gateway - I would like to whitelist only a certain set of IP addresses to access the gateway (without setting up a cloudfront distribution + WAF). I have even tried attaching a policy directly from AWS' documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-policy-language-overview.html but get the same issue.

Comment: So you want users to access it only when they have a certain IP? Then leave out the principal part, keep the rest and attach it to your users as a policy. It is weird that the example policy from AWS does not seem to work.